# How to get values from values.yaml to _helpers.tpl in helm charts

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

This is values.yaml file. It contains the following and when I am trying to get it into _helper.tpl im getting `Helm template failed. Error: render error in "windows/templates/ingresses/windows.yaml": template: windows/templates/_helpers.tpl:38:18: executing "windows.certificate" at <.Values.ingress.enab...>: can't evaluate field ingress in type interface {} : exit status 1`

**values.yaml**

```
ingress:
    enabled: true
    tls: true
    certificate: ''
    issuer:
        name: letsencrypt-staging
    hosts:
        windows:
            - name: ''
            path: /
```

**_helpers.tpl**

```
 {{/*
 Calculate certificate
 */}}
 {{- define "windows.certificate" }}
 {{- printf .Values.ingress.enabled }}  // error line is this. line no 38
 {{- end }}
```

**in windows.yaml**

```
    - secretName: {{ template "windows.certificate" . }} // calling the helper method.
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that when you call the helper, the context is not the root as the definition expects.

Take for example, if you use it in a template like this:

```
{{- range .Values.deployments }}
  {{ $certificate := include "windows.certificate" . }}
{{- end }}
```

The context when calling the helper would be *.Values.deployments*. So, *.Values.ingress.certificate* would point to *.Values.deployments.Values.ingress.certificate*, which of course, does not exist.

At the start of the variables section of the [helm templating guide](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide), you have an example of how `with` blocks affect what `.` means. Reading it might help you understand how to be aware of what you pass to your helper template.

Comment: Where shall I add this code? in _helpers.tpl or where i am calling this helper method. I have modified my question and added how I am calling the helper method. {{ template "windows.certificate" . }}

Comment: We need to see the code that is before you call the helper method. You need to check if there's any `{{range... }}` or `{{with...}}` that might have changed the context

Answer (score 3):

for those having the same problem.
In my case, I had to rename my file from **V**alues.yaml to **v**alues.yaml (mind the lowercase filename).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the indentation try this

**values.yaml**

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  tls: true
  certificate: ''
  issuer:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
  hosts:
    windows:
      - name: ''
        path: /
```

Also some changes on the helpers to control the output of the define block

**_helpers.tpl**

```
 {{/*
 Calculate certificate
 */}}
 {{- define "windows.certificate" }}
 {{- if .Values.ingress.enabled }}
 {{- printf .Values.ingress.certificate }} 
 {{- end }}     
 {{- end }}
```

Comment: Yeah.. !! I checked it but the error is still the same. I have edited my code too

Comment: Check now, I've edited the answer to add some changes on the helper